# How to get words's id in the vocabulary of bag-of-words given the word?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have exploit Bag-of-words model on a bunch of messages as following :

```
    bow_transformer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas).fit(messages['message'])
    B4 = bow_transformer.transform([msg4])
    print B4
    print bow_transformer.get_feature_names()[6736]
    print bow_transformer.get_feature_names()[8013]
```

> (0, 1158) 1
>   (0, 1899)   1
>   (0, 2897)   1
>   (0, 2927)   1
>   (0,
>   4021) 1
>   (0, 6736)   2
>   (0, 7111)   1
>   (0, 7698)   1
>   (0, 8013)   2
>
> say
>
> u

what I need is to given words like **"say"** extract its id **"6736"** (something vise versa of what `bow_transformer.get_feature_names()[6736]` is doning ) ?!

Comment: Can you not just use the `transform` method? i.e. `bow_transformer.transform(['say'])`

Comment: it gave me something like: **(0, 6736)  1** but I only need 6736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the **vocabulary_** property:

```
>>> bow_transformer.vocabulary_.get('say')
6736
```